# Obtaining data from binary tree in constant time

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

pre-order: [image]

post-order: [image]

in-order: [image]

I have a binary tree with pre-order, post-order, and in-order numbers(0 to 11) assigned to the nodes. How do I use in-order number, the pre-order number, and the post-order number in each node to get the size of the sub-tree rooted at given node, u in a constant time?

EDIT:

For example, to determine if w is in the sub-tree of u, you should need the pre-order number of u, the post-order number of u, the pre-order number of w, and the post-order number of w.

Because if pre-order number of w is larger than pre-order number of u, and 
post-order number of w is less than post-order number of u. Then we can conclude that
w is in the sub-tree of u.

Comment: You need to implement b-tree or need to use b-tree? if you need to use b-tree, some library support you.you don't need implement.

Comment: @MinGw You mean if input is 5 then answer should be 0,0 and 12 and it should take constant time in each situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cool puzzle! I hopes its not an assignment, cuz I'm about to spoil it.

`pre_order(u.right) - pre_order(u.left) + post_order(u.right) - post_order(u.left) + 1 == number of nodes in the subtree.

`pre_order(u.right) - pre_order(u.left)` computes the number of nodes in the left child because the "distance" from the beginning of the left child to the beginning of the right child is the size of the left child.

Similarly, `post_order(u.right) - post_order(u.left)` computes the number of nodes in the right child because the difference between end of the left and end of the right child is the size of the right child.

Adding 1 includes the root of the tree itself. Obviously either term could be zero if there are no children on that side.

---

The nodes in the trees shown above do no have names. My understanding is that the numbers in the pictures above represent the value of `pre_order(x)` or `post_order(x)` or `in_order(x)`, where `x` is a node whose name we do not know, but whose position in the tree is obvious to viewers.

In "real life" each node would include: (optional name), in_order value, pre_order value, post_order value, (optional) left child, (optional) right child, and optionally other information.

Consider the bottom-right-most node; `post_order(u)==8`, `post_order(u.left)` is undefined, as is `pre_order(u.left)`, and `in_order(u.right)` and so on, since it has no children.

Consider the node `u` such that `pre_order(u)==post_order(u)==in_order(u)==3`, then `post_order(u.left)==1` and `pre_order(u.right)==5`.

Comment: First of all, it is not assignment. But I might post my assignment after due day. Secondly, you provided a nice approaching of this problem, but your approaching doesn't take constant time, in this problem, you can not actually see the shape of binary trees. You should ONLY use the numbers of each node.

Comment: It is constant time. It uses 4 (or fewer) numbers from the nodes. No searching, iteration, etc.

Comment: "the difference between end of the left and end of the right child" Here how do you get the number in end of the left and end of the right? The only number you know is ONLY one which in the given node,u.

Comment: Node u knows its left and right child, since its a tree. It is a constant time operation to look at the child node (no iteration).

Comment: If you say Node, u knows its left and right child, it works. But I am not sure about this point, since only one Node, u, is given.

Comment: Question, if the number of given Node, u is 8. Will `pre_order(u.left) == 0?`